# Logic App and Function App Development in Visual Studio 2019 Preview

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, visual-studio-2019

I am using the latest Preview version of Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 (16.0.0 Preview 1.1), and I was wondering if I can develop Logic Apps (Logic App Designer) and Function Apps in this version of Visual Studio. To be precise I am trying to use this Extension [Azure Logic Apps Tools for Visual Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VinaySinghMSFT.AzureLogicAppsToolsforVisualStudio-18551).

I am unable to find this extension in Tools -> Extensions and Updates.

Is the extension specifically only for Visual Studio 2017?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say you're right, we don't see Azure Logic Apps Tools for Visual Studio in VS2019 preview, because the extension is restricted for VS2017(as described in [its **Pre-requisites**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VinaySinghMSFT.AzureLogicAppsToolsforVisualStudio-18551)). I assume the upgrade work is underway since it's expected that a preview edition doesn't include everything we need.

For Azure Functions, the extension is built-in once we install Azure Development workload. On VS2019 menus, Help> About Microsoft Visual Studio, we can see Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools 16.0.01169.

Comment: Thanks @Jerry Liu. I guess for the time I will stick with VS2017 for the Logic Apps until 2019 has it available.